# Question regarding single string in parentheses inside print function

Tags: python, python-3.x

- When I do:  `print(())`
  it gives output: 
  `()`
- When I do:
  `print(('abhay', 'bhatt'))`
  it gives output: 
  `(abhay, bhatt)`
- But, when I do:
  `print(('abhay'))`
  it gives output: 
  `abhay`

(ie without parentheses)

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: `('abhay')` just evaluates to `'abhay'` which means consider as `<type 'str'>`. If you want to create `tuple` with consist of only one item add a comma after the item just like `('abhay',)`